The Calendar API now distinguishes events created from Gmail
As of May 30, 2024, Google made a change to the Calendar API such that my Google Script no longer works. I use Google Script to change the color of my "standard" calendar events as well as those created automatically from Gmail messages. Unfortunately, now the former cannot be updated through the Google Calendar API as every time I attempt to make an update or patch using the Advanced Calendar API, I get an error.
Here is the guidance from Google: Temporarily, updates on events with the type “fromGmail” are restricted to the properties reminders, colorId, visibility, status, and extendedProperties.
Here is my code:

  var eventsLocal = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs)["items"];
  for (var i = 0; i < eventsLocal.length; i++) {
    var eventLocal = eventsLocal[i];
    eventLocal.colorId = "10";
    try {
      eventLocal = Calendar.Events.update(
        eventLocal,
        calendarId,
        eventLocal.id);
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log('update threw an exception: ' + e);
    }
  }

Here is the exception:
"API call to calendar.events.update failed with error: Bad Request"
Simple updating of color property of events of type "fromGmail" results in exception thrown every time. Updating of color property of any other event type succeeds every time.

Note: I receive the same Bad Request error when attempting to execute the Update function on a Gmail-created Event object using the Google API Explorer.

I would suggest raising this issue to Google's Official Forum at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues
I replicated your issue and found the same thing.

I've done so https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/359257537

Looks like as of this writing, Google fixed the problem mentioned above.
